# How can I sort Airbnb apartment/room listings by price?

Tags: airbnb

How can I sort Airbnb apartment/room listings by price?

[image]

Comment: I don’t have an Airbnb account, so I won’t post it as an answer, but their [help page](https://www.airbnb.com/help/article/2277/how-does-the--sort-by--filter-work) lists a **Sort by** filter to view the listings by **Price - Low to high**, or **Price - High to low**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Its an intentional design feature by Airbnb designed to incentivize you to pay more, rather than booking the cheapest option. @Alex points out in the comments that [this page](https://www.airbnb.com/help/article/2277/how-does-the--sort-by--filter-work) used to mention a price sorting filter, but the help page is now gone and I likewise can't remember it actually being available in practice.